# Weierstrass factorization theorem, Blaschke Products & Natural boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

Can someone recommend literature for Weierstrass factorization theorem,
Blaschke products & Natural boudary of holomorphic functions? 
I have Rudin's Real & Complex Analysis and Conway's functions of one complex variable but I would like to delve in deeper.